# Projected gradient descent on probability simplex in pytorch

Tags: optimization, pytorch, probability, simplex

I have a matrix A of dimension 1000x70000.
my loss function includes A and I want to find optimal value of A using gradient descent where the constraint is that the rows of A remain in probability simplex (i.e. every row sums up to 1). I have initialised A as given below

```
A=np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(70000),1000)
A=torch.tensor(A,requires_grad=True)
```

and my training loop looks like as given below

```
for epoch in range(500):
    y_pred=forward(X)
    y=model(torch.mm(A.float(),X))
    l=loss(y,y_pred)
    l.backward()
    A.grad.data=-A.grad.data
    optimizer.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    if epoch%2==0:
        print("Loss",l,"\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to accomplish that is not to use `A` directly for computation but use a row normalized version of `A`.

```
# you can keep 'A' unconstrained
A = torch.rand(1000, 70000, requires_grad=True)
```

then divide each row by its summation (keeping row sum always 1)

```
for epoch in range(500):
    y_pred = forward(X)
    B = A / A.sum(-1, keepdim=True) # normalize rows manually
    y = model(torch.mm(B, X))
    l = loss(y,y_pred)
    ...
```

So now, at each step, `B` is the constrained matrix - i.e. the quantity of your interest. However, the optimization would still be on (unconstrained) `A`.

---

Edit: @Umang Gupta remined me in the comment section that OP wanted to have "probability simplex" which means there would be another constraint, i.e. `A >= 0`.

To accomplish that, you may simply apply some appropriate activation function (e.g. `torch.exp`, `torch.sigmoid`) on `A` in each iteration

```
A_ = torch.exp(A)
B = A_ / A_.sum(-1, keepdim=True) # normalize rows
```

the exact choice of function depends on the behaviour of training dynamics which needs to be experimented with.

Comment: You may also want each element of A to be >0.

Comment: @UmangGupta right. I have edited the answer.